# How appropriate it is to use SAML_login with AEM with more than 1m users?

Tags: single-sign-on, aem, saml, saml-2.0, jcr

I am investigating a slow login time and some profile synchronisation problems of a large enterprise AEM project. The system has around 1.5m users. And the website is served by 10 publishers.

The way this project is built, is that they have enabled the SAML_login for all these end-users and there is a third party IDP which I assume SAML_login talks to. I'm no expert on this SSO - SAML_login processes, so I'm trying to understand if this is the correct way to go at the first step.

Because of this setup and the number of users, SAML_login call takes 15 seconds on avarage. This is getting unacceptable day by day as the user count rises. And even more importantly, the synchronization between the 10 publishers are failing occasionally, hence some of the users sometimes can't use the system as they are expected to.

Because the users are stored in the JCR for SAML_login, you cannot even go and check the home/users folder from crx browser. It times out as it is impossible to show 1.5m rows at once. And my educated guess is, that's why the SAML_login call is taking so long.

I've come accross with [articles](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/administering/using/saml-2-0-authenticationhandler.html) that tells how to setup SAML_login on AEM, and this makes it sound legal for what it is used in this case. But in my opinion this is the worst setup ever as JCR is not a well designed quick access data store for this kind of usage scenarios.

My understanding so far is that this approach might work well but with only limited number of users, but with this many of users, it is an inapplicable solution approach. So my first question would be: Am I right? :)

If I'm not right, there is certainly a bottleneck somewhere which I'm not aware of yet, what can be that bottleneck to improve upon?

Comment: What you have described is a bad design, User are created in AEM primarily for authoring/admin purpose, or when they otherwise need to be granted permissions. Creating jcr users for publish site users is not recommended for large number of users. Its inefficient, also Its unsafe - if any of those users were to acquire elevated privileges, due to erroneous privilege assignment or some bug, they can potentially mess up your system.

Comment: @awd I agree with your assessment. But I am curious, what’s a better way to do this where users are not created in JCR?

Comment: I totally agree with you @awd, and I am trying to find a formal document stating this as I need to insist on that to my client.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam I am of opinion that for large number of users' data you need a dedicated db server, I have seen the following high level setup work fairly well - after user authenticates with IDP, basic auth info can be maintained in form of cookies on client browser, if there is a need to deal with more of user data, introduce a db server. any processing needed in aem is done via a service user.

Comment: IIRC, the external identity manager extension authenticates with external IDP but still persists the users in The oak repo. Probably because the ACL implementation requires actual oak users. Which is probably why @TolgaEvcimen’s project has the implementation it does. I don’t have Deep technical knowledge of this, but making an educated guess...

Comment: @AhmedMusallam yes, the ootb saml auth handler creates users in the repo, you can have your own saml response handler though (will have to write some code). @ Tolga - from what I know adobe doesn't say how many users aem can support, let me know if you find any formal document/source. also consider reaching out to adobe support if thats an option, and see what they say.

Comment: @ AhmedMusallam @awd, thanks for your feedbacks. It's interesting that the common sense is to not use jcr for endusers, but we aren't able to locate a formal word for it :) I'll let my organization know about this. Not sure if I can reach out to a adobe support though. I have to check. I'll keep this post updated.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen As far as I know this is a issue you can create a DayCare ticket for and ask for advice.

Comment: Also, please let us know what Adobe's answer is :)

Answer (score 3):

The AEM SAML Authentication handler has some performance limitations with a default configuration.  When your browser does an HTTP POST request to AEM under /saml_login it includes a base 64 encoded "SAMLResponse" request parameter. AEM directly processes that response and does not contact any external systems.

Even though the SAML response is processed on AEM itself, the bottle-necks of the /saml_login call are the following:

1. Initial login where AEM creates the user node for the first time - you can look at creating the nodes ahead of time.  You could write a script to create the SAML user nodes (under /home/users) in AEM ahead of time.
2. During each login when the session is first created - a token node is created under the user node under /home/users/.../{usernode}/.tokens - this can be avoided by enabling the [encapsulated token feature](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/administering/security/encapsulated-token.html).
3. Finally, the last bottle-neck occurs when it saves the SAMLResponse XML under the user node (for later use required for SAML-based logout).  This can be avoided by not implementing SAML-based logout.  The latest com.adobe.granite.auth.saml bundle supports turning off the saving of the SAML response.  Service packs AEM 6.4.8 and AEM 6.5.4 include this feature.  To enable this feature, set the OSGI configuration properties storeSAMLResponse=false and handleLogout=false and it would not store the SAML response.